# Add subtask in a milestone of a specific project

Tags: laravel, database, laravel-8

I am stuck on point and cant make logic of it
Problem:
We have different projects and each of the projects has milestones, and milestones contain certain task that is to be performed in order to achieve a milestone. Now the thing is milestones and task are fixed for all of the projects means every project have the same milestone and the same task initially when we create a project, but we need to add an additional task to some project, how can we achieve this

Table: Projects

| id | Project Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Project 1 |
| 2 | project 2 |

Table: milestones

| id | title |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | front-end |
| 2 | back-end |

table: task

| id | title | m_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | import theme | 1 |
| 2 | add css | 1 |
| 1 | add mediaqueries | 1 |

How do I associate every project with the same milestones and task
and how can I add a new task to a specific project

Answer (score 0):

Add 'project_id' column in your tasks table.

Create new 'fixed_tasks' table (id, title) and put your fixed tasks in this table, maybe you can increase/decrease the fixed tasks in the future.

Create an Event/Listener and when any project created trigger this event/listener and copy tasks from fixed_tasks table to tasks table, with created new project id.

Answer (score 0):

I am working in a similar project these days and this is the Game plan I came with. I hope you this can help you.

I have created the models

- **Template**
- **Template_Milestone** (with a foreign-key to Template)
- **Template_Task** (with a foreign-key to Template_Milestone)

I have created the models

- **Project**
- **Project_Milestone** (with a foreign-key to Project)
- **Project_Task** (with a foreign-key to Project_Milestone)

Process:

1. (user input) Choose **Template**
2. (user input or Automatic) In my case, I manually assign Project_Number
3. (automatic) Copy **template_milestones** instances to **Project_Milestone**
   This instance will be related(FK) to the project number
4. (automatic) Copy **template_Task** instances to **Project_Task**
   This instance will be related(FK) to the template_milestone

Once the initial set-up is completed, I can CRUD Project_Milestones and Project_Tasks as needed and Template wont be affected.

5. Create, Retrieve, Update, Delete **Milestone** (user)
6. Create, Retrieve, Update, Delete **Task** (user)

I can CRUD the Templates a any time and this will not have any consequences to projects because the Project will have his own Milestones and Tasks

---

I am in Testing fase and so far is working well.
I encourage you to keep looking.
You might end up finding a better way or even better designing you own.